# Question regarding stochastic independence

Tags: probability, independence

Let $X,Y,Z$ be random variables and pairwise independent, i.e. $X$ independent from $Y$, $Y$ indepedent from $Z$, and $X$ independent from $Z$. I am interested in a rigorous argument, why $ (X,Y) $ is independent from $Z$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Counterexample**: Let $\Omega$ be the sample space consisting of all the permutations of $(1,2,3)$ as well as the three vectors $(1,1,1), (2,2,2)$ and $(3,3,3)$ (total: $3!+3$ elements in $\Omega$).
One vector is chosen at random from $\Omega$, denoted by $(X,Y,Z)$.
Clearly, each of these is uniform over $\{1,2,3\}$ and they are pairwise independent, but given $(X,Y)$ the value of $Z$ is uniquely determined, so $(X,Y)$ and $Z$ are not independent.

Comment: Why are $X, Y,Z$ pairwise independent? E.g. the choice of $X$ influences the choice of $Y$, doesn't it?

Comment: Suppose $X=1$. Then the triplet can be one of the three $(1,1,1), (1,2,3), (1,3,2)$, so $Y$ is one of $1,2,3$ with equal probabilities.

Comment: In the same vein, but possibly simpler:  Let $P(X=+1)=P(X=-1)=1/2$, let $Y$ be independent of $X$, with the same law, and let $Z=XY$.  For each pair of variables all four $(\pm1,\pm1)$ cases are equally likely, but only half of the possible $(X,Y,Z)=(\pm1,\pm1,\pm1)$ cases are realizable.

Comment: Thanks, to both of you.

Comment: Thanks @kimchilover, I knew there is a simpler example, but couldn't recall it and mine was the first came to my mind.